# Layers "visible" but not showing for rotating doge emoji

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So the vision is a rotating doge head for an emoji.

I made thirty-six layers which were visible before switching to the Motion workspace. After moving the layers along the timeline, I noticed my pictures not showing up, despite the eyeball visibilty icon.

I'm new to Photoshop. What concept do I need to know to get the images to show again?

[image: Visible layers not showing]

Edit: PS disabled the option for opacity

[image: Can't change opacity]

Edit 2: So I can update the opacity on some but not others. What's going on?

[image: Can't change the layer opacity on some layers]

Edit 3: I'm able to change it... if I move the layer up to the top... why am I not able to change the opacity without doing this?

[image: Move to the top to be able to edit]

---

Edit 4: I see that this happened after messing with the timeline in the Motion workspace.

What about this causes it to become uneditable?

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate this. Can you write the exact steps to reproduce the issue in a new file? Sounds like some sort of a bug

Comment: Thanks for your time, @SergeyKritskiy  I edited this (#4) to show that a layer becomes uneditable (for opacity and fill at least) after shifting a frame in the timeline panel. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: what do you mean by 'messing with': in what way? I have no issues editing layers opacity after an image was converted to an animation

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy After you converted it to a timeline (not a frame animation), and after you slid a a frame to the right--like the new gif in the fourth edit--were you able to adjust the opacity of that layer?